# Custom layout based on existed layout

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls

I'm trying to create custom layout for android. It normally draws on screen, but without inner views. Draws only my group_box.xml. How i can get access from my custom layout to inner views (TextView with id test) or how to draw they?

main.xml

```
<my.example.GroupBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40sp">
        <TextView android:text="TEST"
                  android:id="@+id/test"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </my.example.GroupBox>
```

group_box.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/groupbox">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/groupboxContent"
                  android:id="@+id/content"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <TextView style="@style/groupboxLabel"
              android:id="@+id/caption"
              android:text="@string/visit"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

GroupBox.java

```
public class GroupBox extends LinearLayout {

    public GroupBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_box, this);
    }

    public GroupBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_box, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can access to the elements via setters and getters.

put this in your GroupBox.java

```
caption = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption);

 public void setLabel(CharSequence text) {
        caption.setText(text);
    }
```

add an id to your control in xml:

```
<my.example.GroupBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
android:id="mycontrol">
        <TextView android:text="TEST"
                  android:id="@+id/test"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </my.example.GroupBox>
```

then find your control in the main activity and do this:

```
yourcontrol = (GroupBox) findViewById(R.id.mycontrol)

yourcontrol.setLabel("test");
```

Comment: You do not fully understand me. I want setting views inside <my.example.GroupBox> TextView with id test in example into LinearLayout with id content in group_box.xml, and want to do this via xml not from the code like in your example with caption. Thanks

Comment: ok sry. you can't put this view in <my.example.GroupBox> and access to it in class GroupBox. You can just access from the view, or the activity which inflates the main.xml. think about: you can add the <my.example.GroupBox> to other layouts. if you yould access in GroupBox to an view you don't have had added to the XML you would get an NullPointerException.

Comment: But how Android do this in LinearLayout or any other layout?

Comment: try this tutorial how to crate a own view. http://www.anddev.org/custom_widget_-_mygridlayout_divide_to_grid_and_layout_it-t1792.html